# React how to display multiple components of different origin on the same parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dashboard

I'm trying to build a Dashboard with React Js and I would like to know how you could display multiple components, but as widgets, which mean you need to be able to add them in any order and in any quantity. My problem is that I can't find a way to render a map of components.

The user may be able to add a widget to his dashboard by clicking a button, or remove them the same way, so I won't know how many of what components will be rendered

I would like to do something like, when the user clicks on a widget, it adds it to the dashboard, but I don't know how to do that.

I've tried to store components in a map, then with a forEach loop display them all by returning a div containing the component:

```
import Weather from '...'
import Currency from '...'
import News from '...'

const map = [Weather, Currency, News]

const runAll = () => {
    map.forEach((fcn) => {
        let runner = fcn
        runner()
    })
}

runAll()
```

I've searched many stack and other forums questions, without finding what I needed

Do you guys have an idea of what I could do to solve this ?

Comment: Are test, toto, tata the component widgets you're trying to display?

Comment: Yes, i'm going to rename them to something else for comprehension

Comment: What is the problem with displaying them in your render with tags like
render(){ return{ <test/> <toto/> <tata/>}}

Comment: I can't add or remove the components I want to display automatically, let's say the user clicks on a new widget to add in the dashboard, I have to display a new component with the already displayed ones, so I thought of a map where I could save the displayed components and remove them in the case the user want to delete them

Comment: You need to have some way to store a reference to the components that the user selected. Whether you want to do this using cookies, localStorage, a database or just in memory, your problem isn't rendering a list of components, it's figuring out what the list should be.

Comment: Just keep a state (array) that will hold all widgets added by user, and do a iteration over the state to render the components. remove items from state when user triggers remove action and the components will get rerendered. save this state to some persistence storage (localstorage, database etc) if needed and render the saved content when page reloads. For saving to persistence storage you could assign some constant values for each widgets, so that when that constant value come you could render the corresponding component.

Comment: So let's say I use a database, I should try to save the widgets in a database, and then load from the database ? I see the idea, but my other problem is how to render them, just as @yainspan said, I need to figure out how my list should be so I will be able to render all my list on the parent component

Comment: no need to save widgets to database, just save some constant values. eg -
const widgets = {weather : 1, news: 2}
save these values to database as json with props you needed, and then retrieve this json which will render components based on it

[{type: 1, prop1: "val"},{type: 2, prop1: "val"}]

const renderWidgets = (array) =>{
    array.foreach((widget)=>{
  switch(widget){
   case widgets.weather:
    renderWeather(widget);
   break;
   .
   .
   .
   etc
  }
 })
}

Comment: Hmm thank you, I'll try this out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to be able to easily render 2 things:

1. a list of widgets that the user can click and add in the dashboard
2. the actual dashboard. All selected widgets in a list (with a remove capability)

Let's first figure out what our `state` should be that also feeds the components 1 and 2.

- For the 1st one we need the full list of available widgets. Since this is static (we have 3 widgets available) this can be expresses through a static mapping (a simple javascript object) declared once.
- For the 2nd one we need an array of the user selected widgets. That's the dynamic part. We need to be able to set the **initial** widgets shown and have the capability to **add** and **remove** widgets from this list, allowing the same widget appearing more that once.

##### Static widget mapping

This should be a mapping between an identifier and the react widget component and should look like this:

```js
import News from "./News";
import Weather from "./Weather";
import Currency from "./Currency";

const widgetsMapping = {
  news: News,
  weather: Weather,
  currency: Currency
};
```

##### Widgets state

This is an array of widget identifiers (the keys from the static mapping) that the user wants in the dashboard. Also we need **add** and **remove** methods. Using `useState` we can write this like below:

```js
const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState(["weather", "news"]);

const addWidget = (widget) => {
  setWidgets([...widgets, widget]);
};

const removeWidget = (index) => {
  const updated = [...widgets];
  updated.splice(index, 1);
  setWidgets(updated);
};
```

##### Rendering

###### Dashboard

Then we can render the dashboard by iterating our `widget` state array:

```js
{widgets.map((widget, index) => {
  const Widget = widgetsMapping[widget];
  return (
    <Widget
      key={`${widget}${index}`}
      removeWidget={() => removeWidget(index)}
    />
  )
})}
```

`removeWidget` prop can be used to let a widget remove itself when sth is clicked.

###### List of available widgets

Here we will iterate through all available widgets from our static mapping and render all of them with the **add** functionality bound to them.

```
{Object.keys(widgetsMapping).map((widget) => (
  <button key={widget} onClick={() => addWidget(widget)}>
    {widget}+
  </button>
))}
```

You can find a **full working example** in [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hoover-nnm7q?file=/src/App.js:583-749). Some assumptions were made about how you want to add and remove widgets but the main idea remains the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what I want, I'll try this out and let you know !

Comment: @fgkolf - You are a pure Genius!

Answer (score 1):

Keep a state (array) that holds widgets added by user. Define constants for widgets and save these constants to your persistance storage.

const widgets = {weather : 1, news: 2}
save these values to database as json with properties configured by user if needed, and then retrieve this json and render components based on it

sample JSON structure to save - [{type: 1, prop1: "val"},{type: 2, prop1: "val"}]

```
const renderWidgets = (array) => {
    const widgets = [];
    array.foreach((widget) => {
        switch(widget) {
            case widgets.weather:
                widgets.push(<Weather ...props/>);
            break;
            .
            .
            .
            etc
        }
    });
    
    return widgets;
}
```